# Text Vertical Alignment on DIV

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, text-alignment

I need to align text inside those text inside the  vertically middle in all the screen resolutions.

Can any one suggest please?

[image]

Comment: Share the code...

Comment: [link] https://jsfiddle.net/gkc2xg11/

Comment: Currently i have used padding and min-height property. But the alignment differs on each resolutions

Comment: I have edited my ans pls check it....

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/kr9cjc3L/2/
I took the liberty to clean up your code a little as well :)

Comment: @Santhoshkumar. It works. Awesome. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Welcome @Raj...

Comment: @AlexanderJohansen. You are free to edit. ;) I got another method from you to implement. Thanks to you too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following code

```css
.textBox{display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;}
.cont-bx1{background-color:#9f2f1f; color:#ffffff; text-align:center;  min-height:200px; font-weight:bold; border: 1px solid #ffffff;}
.cont-bx2{background-color:#ef9030; color:#ffffff; text-align:center; min-height:200px; font-weight:bold; border: 1px solid #ffffff;}
.cont-bx3{background-color:#df6221; color:#ffffff; text-align:center; min-height:200px; font-weight:bold; border: 1px solid #ffffff;}
.cont-bx4{background-color:#df6221;  color:#ffffff; text-aligncenter;  min-height:200px; font-weight:bold; border: 1px solid #ffffff; }
.cont-bx5{background-color:#9f2f1f; color:#ffffff; text-align:center; min-height:200px; font-weight:bold; border: 1px solid #ffffff;}
.cont-bx6{background-color:#9f2f1f; color:#ffffff; text-align:center; min-height:200px; font-weight:bold; border: 1px solid #ffffff;}
.cont-bx7{background-color:#ef9030; color:#ffffff; text-align:center; min-height:200px; font-weight:bold; border: 1px solid #ffffff;}
.cont-bx8{background-color:#df6221; color:#ffffff; text-align:center; min-height:200px; font-weight:bold; border: 1px solid #ffffff;}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="col-lg-4 cont-bx1 textBox">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 cont-bx2 textBox">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 cont-bx3 textBox">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="col-lg-6 cont-bx4 textBox">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 cont-bx5 textBox">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="col-lg-4 cont-bx6 textBox">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 cont-bx7 textBox">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 cont-bx8 textBox">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use flexbox to align items.

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

Full example here: [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRZBXQ)